# Ionic Capacitor with Android flavor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm really new to Ionic and I'm trying to write a plugin using Capacitor to talk to the native android layer. But right now I could not find anything to deal with Android flavors.

Is there anything that helps Capacitor to build with the right flavors. Or maybe I'm just getting the wrong idea, please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by android flavors?

Answer (score 1):

Ionic works by delegating the whole building process to the pertinent device builder, XCode for iOS or Android Studio. So, in order to build a distinct flavour for Android you can use Android Studio's solution.

The flavours are set on the file `android/app/build.gradle`<sup>1</sup>

```
android {
...
    defaultConfig {
...
        flavorDimensions "default"
        productFlavors {
            demo {
                versionName "0.0.1-demo"
            }
            full{

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the console you can build your project with

```
./android/gradlew -p android :app:assemble$FLAVOUR$TYPE
```

or from the Android Studio GUI `Build -> Select build variant`<sup>2</sup>

Any way, I've been unable to inject JS code using this method. In order to emulate this behaviour, probably the use of Webpack is for the best.

In case you are using Angular CLI, a simple solution could be to use distinct `angular.projects.app.architect.build.configurations` for each flavour

```
"architect":
{
  "build":
  {
    "configurations" :
    {    
      "demo":
      {
         "fileReplacements": [{
            "replace": "src/ui/menu.ts",
             "with": "src/ui/menu.demo.ts"
          }]
       }
    }
  }
}
```

and then build for Android with:

```
ionic capacitor build android --configuration="${FLAVOUR}" --release
```

---

<sup>1</sup>https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants
<sup>2</sup>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWnkWHF2lFQ

Comment: You can also run `./gradlew assembleDemoRelease` (for example) from the project's directory to build the "demo" flavor with build type "release".